# Is it fine to wipe my ears more than once during wudu?

Tags: wudu

I'm quite careful when making wudu and ghusl. I try to perform every single step perfectly. Actually, while performing ghusl, I was making wudu and while making masah for ears I wiped them more than once just to make sure. Is it fine and permissible?

Comment: I'd say three times is even sunnah.